# how to remove only clicked element of a class not all in single line by using 'this' without using click function?

Tags: jquery-ui

```
<div id="id_div" style="display: none">
    <div class="cls_divs">
        <input class="cls_file" type='file' name='file' />  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="upload()"><img              '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/upload.bmp' width='80' height='30'/></a>
    <a class="cls_delete" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteo()"><img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/delete.bmp' width='80'   height='30'/></a>

    </div>
</div>

function deleteo() {
    count--;
    $(".cls_divs .cls_delete").click(function () {
        $(".cls_divs").remove();

    });
}
```

in jquery code i have problem at "$(".cls_divs").remove();" line that is, this line removes all the dynamicaly appended div but i want to delete only clicked(this) div not all, of class .cls_divs .... not of .cls_delete class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html you don't need to assign onclick function. You can use jquery on() method. Have a look how I did it.

```
div id="id_div" style="display: none">
    <div class="cls_divs">
    <input class="cls_file" type='file' name='file' />  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="upload()"><img '<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/upload.bmp' width='80' height='30'/></a>
    <a class="cls_delete" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/delete.bmp' width='80'   height='30'/></a>

</div>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$(".cls_divs .cls_delete").on("click",function (e) {
    // make sure that count variable is global.
    count --;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This will work perfectly. I have checked that in jsfiddle. Have a look at jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5ZEJt/

Answer (score 0):

use this keyword:

```
$(this).remove();
```

here is complete code:

```
function deleteo() {
    count--;       
    $(this).parents('div.cls_divs').remove();       
}
```

You do not need to bind event on click in `deleteo`, if you really need to use `on()` instead of `click()` and parents will select parent use it with class name filter.